# negative slope of a triangle given only the sides

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, slope

So my teacher gave me this graph and I needed to calculate the slope of the hypothenuse or `f'(0.25)`.

[image]

So 62/121 is positive and I can see that the slope is negative. Given this and only this information is it correct to just add the negative sign? my answer was something like:

> 62/121= 0.51 but we add the negative since its going downwards so its -0.51

I'm sorry if this is a dumb question but I've been searching for hours and I guess I don't know what to search for

Also, isn't it a little odd that the teacher used different coordinate systems for the sides of the triangle?

Edit:

This is a calculus class but I put the tags trigonometry since is just calculating the slope. The question was

> Find f '(0.25)

Comment: Slope is $~\displaystyle \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = \frac{-62}{121}.$

Comment: @user2661923 sure but where did you get the negative sign?  did you just add it? so my answer was correct?

Comment: Your answer was correct.  As $x$ increased in value $(121)$, $y$ decreased in value $(-62)$.